# Birt parameter and dataset

Tags: parameters, dataset, birt

I would like to show a report using a parameter, depending what parameter the user chose It should show a specific dataset. is that possible?

This is why i need to show different **DATASETS** depending on the value chosen in the parameter:

I have a report and I need to integrate it in one if possible. This report have the parameters of start and finish date, but now also want to have a service parameter. For example i need a report to shows me clients that are related to service A, the available services are : A,B,C,D,E so that's why I'm using **service** as parameter, but the same report depending on what service it is, changes and needs to show not only clients but also employees related to the service.

i.e.
Report 1 : Show clients related to service A
Report 2 : Show clients related to service B
Report **3** : Show clients and employees related to service C
Report 4 : Show clients related to service D
Report **5** : Show clients and employees related to service E

Answer (score 1):

If data set has to be swapped during runtime:

1. Name report item bound to one of data sets in the *Property Editor* view, i.e. to `myTable`.
2. In the *beforeFactory* script assign appropriate Data Set:

   ```
   var myTable = reportContext.getDesignHandle().findElement('myTable');
   myTable.setProperty('dataSet', 'myChoosenDataSet');
   ```

Another, simpler approach: if it will be sufficient, you can just hide data items when not needed. Put a *visibility* condition in the *Property Editor* view, for the item to be hidden.

Yet another approach: adjust sql query in the Data Set *beforeOpen* script:

```
if (params['service'].value == 'foo') {
    this.queryText = "select * from foo where foo.bar = ?";
}
```